# Error regarding geom_map:"Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0"

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(wesanderson)
library(animation)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
states_map <-map_data("state")

StateCodes <- c("AL","AK","CA","AL","AK","CA")
year <- c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011)
n <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3)
data <- data.frame(StateCodes,year,n)

saveGIF({
  for (i in 2010:2011) {

    m<-ggplot(subset(data,year==i), aes(map_id = StateCodes)) +
      geom_map(aes(fill = (n)), map = states_map, color ="black") +
      expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
      theme_few()+
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
            axis.title = element_blank(), 
            axis.text =  element_blank()) +
      scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue") +
      guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 10, barheight = .5)) + 
      ggtitle(paste("Value in Year",i))
    print(m)


  } 

}, interval = 1, movie.name = "value_usa.gif", ani.width = 800, ani.height = 600 )
```

Upon running the above code, I got the error `Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`. There were a number of resources which urged to use `as.factor(n)` and that didn't work either. I have reduced the above example as much as I can for easy understanding. I had done a similar project which worked fine . It can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/adhok93/d/NUFORC/ufo-sightings/ufo-sightings-in-the-usa)

Comment: `Statecodes`contains abbreviation of the `region` in `states_map` which are fully named. I'd suggest keeping it consistent.

Comment: I am getting an error while running the line , states_map <- map_data("state"), Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list.

Comment: @Haboryme Yes, you are right . I did not realise my silly mistake until you pointed it out. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Change capitalization on two lines:

```
Statecodes <- c("AL","AK","CA","AL","AK","CA")

...

m<-ggplot(subset(data,year==i), aes(map_id = Statecodes)) +
```